# python selenium datepicker gets cleared

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I'm developing a python app that sets form componentes of a certain webpage (developed using vue3.js)

I'm able to set a datepicker's value, but, after that, next operation clears the dapicker away.

I must be doing something really fool, but I'm out of ideas.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from selenium                                   import webdriver

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
driver_headfull     =   None
try:
    driver_headfull = webdriver.Firefox()
    firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR WHEN CREATING webdriver.Firefox()')
    print("Please, verify you have installed: firefox and that geckodriver.exe's is in %PATH%")
    print(e)
    sys.exit(5)

#navigate to url
driver_headfull.get('http://a_certain_ip')
#set a datepicker
element_to_interact_with_headfull       = driver_headfull.find_element_by_id('datesPolicyEffectiveDate')
driver_headfull.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2020-07-01';", element_to_interact_with_headfull)

#set a <div> that behaves like a <select>.
element_to_interact_with_headfull       = driver_headfull.find_element_by_id('industryDescription')
driver_headfull.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_to_interact_with_headfull)
element_pseudo_select_option_headfull   = driver_headfull.find_element_by_id('descriptionIndustryoption0')
driver_headfull.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element_pseudo_select_option_headfull)
#   this very last instruction resets value of html_id=datesPolicyEffectiveDate (datepicker)


while(True):
    pass
```

Any ideas will be **so** welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a pain. I'll post it in case it's of any use for someone.

It seems the component was reloaded, and I was setting the son of the component by means of
`arguments[0].value = '2020-07-01';`

so the parent wouldn't see the change, and would automatically reload the child with a default (empty) value.

Adding the following snippet solved my trouble:

```
driver_headfull.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2021-07-01';", element_to_interact_with_headfull)
driver_headfull.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));", element_to_interact_with_headfull)
```